# New water level when object is partially submerged

Tags: calculus, volume

[image]

Hello

My question is about the new water level when an object is partially submerged. As the water level raises, it swallows a different amount of volume of the ball and so changes at different rates, from which I am assuming calculus is involved. Aside from that I am unsure of how to begin answering this question, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I've thought about it for a while and I have an idea.

The height right now is 1, so if we consider half the sphere (which is what would be submerged if the water didn't rise) we see that we are essentially adding half of $$4/3*pi*1^3$$

This raises the water level by a certain known amount, which now submerges a little more of the sphere. This raises the water level by a very small amount, submerging a tiny fraction of the sphere. As the volume being submerged is getting smaller maybe I can try taking some kind of limit.

Comment: Does the object remain resting on the bottom? Otherwise you need density.

Comment: The volume of a spherical cap of height $h$ and radius $r$ is given by ${\pi \over 3} h^2 (3r-h)$. You can use calculus to derive this if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the new water level is at $ h $, then, from the balance of volumes

$ 25 + V_1 = 25 h $

Where $V_1$ is the volume of the sphere between levels of $0$ an $h$,

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
V_1 &= \dfrac{r^3}{3} (2 \pi) (1 - \dfrac{r - h}{r} ) - \dfrac{\pi}{3}(r - h) (r^2 - (r - h)^2 ) \\ 
&= \dfrac{\pi}{3} ( 2 r^2 h - (r - h) (2 r h - h^2) )\\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{3}(2 r^2 h - 2 r^2 h + r h^2 + 2 r h^2  - h^3 ) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{3}(3 r h^2 - h^3 ) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{3} h^2 ( 3 r - h) \\
 \end{split} \end{equation} $

Therefore, since $r = 1$, the equation we want to solve is

$ \dfrac{\pi}{3} h^2 (3 - h ) = 25 (h - 1) $

The solution of which is $ h = 1.095774 $

Comment: Yes this is definitely an acceptable way of solving the question thanks

Comment: Where did the formula for v1 come from, did you integrate a portion of a semicircle?

Comment: I have modified the derivation, there was a sign error.  Now the formula is correct.  This changes the final numeric answer.  As for the derivation of $V_1$ it is the difference between the volume of a spherical sector and the volume of the associated cone.